# Nginx Ingress Kube

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm confused about nginx ingress with Kubernetes. I've been able to use it with "basic nginx auth" (unable to do so with `oauth2` yet).

I've installed via helm:

`helm install stable/nginx-ingress --name app-name --set rbac.create=true`

This creates two services, an `nginx-ingress-controller` and an `nginx-ingress-backend`.

When I create an ingress, this ingress is targeted towards one and only one `nginx-ingress-controller`, but I have no idea how:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tomcat
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: "Authentication Required - foo"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  rules:
  - host:
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: tomcat-deployment-service 
          servicePort: 8080
```

When I get this Ingress from the output of `kubectl get ingress -n kube-system`, it has a public, external IP.

What's ***concerning*** is that `basic-auth` **DOESN'T APPLY** to that external IP; it's wide open! Nginx authentication only kicks in when I try to visit the `nginx-ingress-controller`'s IP.

I have a lot of questions.

1. How do I made an ingress created from `kubectl apply -f
   ingress.yaml` target a specific nginx-ingress-controller?
2. How do I keep this new `ingress` from having an external IP?
3. Why isn't `nginx` authentication kicking in?
4. What IP am I suppose to use (the `nginx-ingress-controller` or the
   generated one?)
5. If I'm suppose to use the generated IP, what about the one from the controller?

I have been searching for descent, working examples (and pouring over sparse, changing documentation, and github issues) for *literally* days.

EDIT:

In this "official" [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/basic/), it's unclear as to weather or not `http://10.2.29.4/` is the IP from the `ingress` or the `controller`. I assume the `controller` because when I run this, the other doesn't even authenticate (*it let's me in without asking for a password*). Both IP's I'm using are external IPs (publicly available) on GCP.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have some concept definition misunderstanding.

1. Ingress is not a job ( Nor a service, nor a pod ). It is just a configuration. It cannot have "IP". think of ingress as a routing rule or a routing table in your cluster.
2. `Nginx-ingress-controller` is the service with type `Loadbalancer` with actual running pods behind it that facilitates those ingress rules that you created for your cluster.
3. `Nginx-ingress-backend` is likely to be a `default-backend` that your `nginx-ingress-controller` will route to if no matching routes are found. see [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/default-backend/)
4. In general, your `nginx-ingress-controller` should be the only entry of your cluster. Other services in your cluster should have type `ClusterIP` such that they are not exposed to outside the cluster and only accessible through your `nginx-ingress-controller`. In you case, since your service could be access from outside directly, it should not be of type `ClusterIP`. Just change the service type to get it protected.

Based on above understanding, I will glad to provide further help for the question you have.

Some readings:

1. What is ingress: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/
2. K8s Services and external accessibility: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types